# Run multiple clones of a model in parallel

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, keras, evolutionary-algorithm

So I am trying to implement a reinforcement learning algorithm using Evolution Strategy.

The principle is to clone your original model N times (let's say 100 times), apply some noise on those 100 clones, run them, check which ones are giving the best results and use that to update the original model.

Now I am trying to put each of these clones in a different thread and run them all in parallel.

Here is my Worker class :

```
class WorkerThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self, action_dim, img_dim, sigma, sess):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        #sess = tf.Session()
        self.actor = ActorNetwork(sess, action_dim, img_dim)
        self.env = Environment()
        self.reward = 0
        self.N = {}
        self.original_model = None
        self.sigma = sigma

    def setActorModel(self, model):
        self.original_model = model

    def run(self):
        k = 0
        for l in self.actor.model.layers:
            if len(np.array(l.get_weights())) > 0:
                # First generate some noise
                shape = (np.array(l.get_weights()[0])).shape
                if len(shape) == 2:
                    self.N[k] = np.random.randn(shape[0], shape[1])
                else:
                    self.N[k] = np.random.randn(shape[0], shape[1], shape[2], shape[3])
                # 2nd set weights using original model's weights and noise
                la = self.original_model.layers[k]
                self.actor.model.layers[k].set_weights((la.get_weights()[0] + self.sigma * self.N[k], la.get_weights()[1]))

            k += 1

        ob = self.env.reset()

        while True:
            action = self.actor.predict(np.reshape(ob['image'], (1, 480, 480, 3)))
            ob = self.env.step(action[0])

            if ob['done']:
                self.reward = ob['reward']
                break
```

So each worker thread has it's own model, and when running I set the weights using the original's model weights.

At that point I get the following error

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1219, in set_weights
    K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2365, in batch_set_value
    assign_op = x.assign(assign_placeholder)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/variables.py", line 594, in assign
    return state_ops.assign(self._variable, value, use_locking=use_locking)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/state_ops.py", line 276, in assign
    validate_shape=validate_shape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_state_ops.py", line 59, in assign
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 350, in _apply_op_helper
    g = ops._get_graph_from_inputs(_Flatten(keywords.values()))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 5055, in _get_graph_from_inputs
    _assert_same_graph(original_graph_element, graph_element)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 4991, in _assert_same_graph
    original_item))
ValueError: Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(5, 5, 3, 24), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("conv2d_11/kernel:0", shape=(5, 5, 3, 24), dtype=float32_ref).
```

In the above code sample I use the same tensorflow session in all the threads. I tried creating a different session for each but I get the same error.

I have little knowledge about tensorflow, does anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the same graph in all threads. Create a tf.Graph() in your main thread and wrap your per-thread function in "with my_graph.as_default():".

Comment: I thought it was using the default graph by default, and I think it does as my layers have names like `dense_1` for original model, and `dense_41` for last clone. Shouldn't all the clones use their own graph instead?

Comment: No they should all use the same graph. Starting separate threads can create separate per-thread graphs I think.